# Rest Client Elasticsearch Host setup

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, client

I am using Elasticsearch in one project an locally my client is located at localhost:9200, but when I am on dev environment my Elasticsearch client is at https://elasticsearch.eu:443/v1/elastic. When i am creating the Java client I use: 
RestClient restClient =RestClient.builder( new HttpHost(Host, port)).build(). Which is the correct way to set the Host and port for the second URL, since we have an extra path?

Comment: I need this too. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

In the version 7.17, according to [Java Low Level REST Client - Initialization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/java-rest-low-usage-initialization.html)

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();
```